# PDF is not rendering in Safari

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I am using PDF.js to view PDF in the browser. It works fine with  Mozilla and Chrome but it is not rendering PDF on safari(5.1.7) in my window and iPAd4.

I am using the same code as given in this [PDF Example](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/index.html#interactive-examples) but it's not working and gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions')
```

This example also does not work with Safari:
https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

What am I missing to make this work in Safari?

[My sample fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/pdfjs/9engc9mw/)

**I am Using Safari Version 5.1.7**

Comment: Example you provided works in my Safari 13.1.2...

Comment: You are most likely running your javascript code before the pdf.js script has loaded. Can you show your full HTML?

Comment: @ThadBlankenship My code is here https://jsfiddle.net/pdfjs/9engc9mw/

Comment: Safari Version 5.1.7 was used in 2012. I don't think you will find any support for that.

Comment: Last version Apple released for Windows was in 2012.

Comment: You're missing about 8 years of progress. And to be honest, Safari on Windows was a bit of a problem child even in 2012.